# How to implement an Embed-In Slider to Display Data?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement a slider to display data, but this slider must be only a small part of my view controller (it's not a full-page slider UIPageViewController).

Here is an example from Steam app to make it concrete:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyegZ.jpg (small slider at the top)

What UI element should i use to implement such a slider and fill it with data? A horizontal scroll view? Page view controller? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed UIPageViewController into any view. Also you can use UICollectionView with paging.

https://gist.github.com/michaelevensen/3bbd36e417e463c01368ff5669a428c0
https://medium.com/@_josetony/page-slider-with-uicollectionview-in-swift-4-172c948128bd

Comment: Thank you, which one would you suggest for this kind of design? PageVC or a collection view? Or are they same?

Comment: UIPageViewController is much more simple than implementing slider with UICollectionView, but has limitations for customizing. It's up to you